# Update Status of facebook while using php SDK in my app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to update status on my wall But the thing is there are the link is compulsory to post on my wall.
I would like to update only Message not link on the wall.
Here is my sample code:-

---

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'MY_APP_ID',
            'secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRETE_KEY',
            'cookie' => true

        ));
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
            'access_token' => $_SESSION['active']['access_token'],
            'link' => 'www.ermehar.com',
            'message' => 'Hello World..!',
        ));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ret_obj);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

Is this possible to update status without using of the 'Link'..?

Comment: RTFDocs please: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible to update status without using of the 'Link'..?

**Yes.** You can post on the wall without any link.

Comment: Hello There. I already tried without link but it is not working.. the code is:
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
            'access_token' => $_SESSION['active']['access_token'],
            'link' => 'www.ermehar.com',
            'message' => 'Hello World..!',
        ));

Comment: I can see `link` in this code?  `'link' => 'www.ermehar.com'`

Comment: Now my code is:-
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array(
            'access_token' => $_SESSION['active']['access_token'],
            'message' => 'Hello World..!',
        ));

Comment: What response are you getting? Value of `$ret_obj`?

Comment: How's this possible? Try the same here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: I tried man... I works only for single time and when I change the message again facing the problem

Comment: Well if you dont want to debug, your call, I just wanted to help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

ya it is possible to update on your wall . the below caode and link help you properly how post status in facebook wall using php
http://scriptime.blogspot.in/2012/12/facebook-status-updates-using-php-sdk.html

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$facebook_id = $userdata['id'];
$params = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => $status
);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebook_id/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

for more details about ho set up environments check this link